# how to show cart in any page in Opencart cms

Tags: php, opencart

I'm an amateur when it comes to working with Opencart.
I want to add a menu item to my website which will open the carts table like a pop up.
I tried to include cart.php to head but the result was a nearly empty table.
Is there anyway to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The default home screen in 2.3.0.2 has such a button.  So the elements you'd need to extract to put it on other screens:

`catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/header.tpl`:

`<li><a href="<?php echo $shopping_cart; ?>" title="<?php echo $text_shopping_cart; ?>"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md"><?php echo $text_shopping_cart; ?></span></a></li>`

then from `catalog/controller/common/header.php`

`$data['cart'] = $this->load->controller('common/cart');
$data['shopping_cart'] = $this->url->link('checkout/cart');`

Comment: Ty so much. even in the OC forum I didn't get any answer.

Comment: But I want to display the table not just put a link in the menu.

Comment: You would have to reproduce all the logic in the controller and view for the cart then.